# Proving that if $f$ is equal to $g$ asymtotically then their distance tends to zero

Tags: asymptotics, probability-limit-theorems

How could I prove **via limit definition** that from
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = 1
$$
derives
$$
\left| f(n) - g(n) \right| \to 0
$$
?

Previous attempt took me to
$$
\left| f(n) - g(n) \right| < \varepsilon \left| g(n) \right| \qquad \forall \varepsilon \space \text{fixed}, \forall n \ge n_0
$$
which is not useful since $\varepsilon \cdot |g|$ might be not that low ceil (...I'm thinking the case when $g$ goes to infinity).

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you have the right question? Consider the functions $f(x) = x+1$, and $g(x) = x$.

If you assume that $|f(x) - g(x)| \rightarrow 0$, it's not terribly hard to show that their ratio tends to 1.

Hint: rewrite $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ as $\frac{g(x) - (g(x) - f(x))}{g(x)}$.

Comment: It can be even worse. $|f(x)-g(x)|$ may be unbounded: Try $f(x)=x+\sqrt x$, $g(x)=x$.